# Difference between overflow/underflow when using numpy.log and math.log

Tags: python, numpy, math

This is not meant to be a debugging question. However, I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why `numpy.log(factorial(n))` would refuse to take any value where n was greater than 20. It would spit out an attribute error saying: `'int' object has no attribute 'log'`and a type error saying:`loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable log method` whenever n was greater than 20.

I decided to then use `math.log(factorial(n))` and to my surprise everything worked as expected.

I was wondering if anyone had experience with numpy or knows more about the different math/numpy functions that could explain this error.

Here is an example of where I was using the log function:

```
math.log(math.factorial(n))
```

*Edit to remove my print statement that I used to test the results

Comment: @HeapOverflow perhaps I should delete my code from the post. However I needed to create my own factorial method for a class which is how I came to see this issue.

Comment: Random guess: it couldn't convert your integer to float without losing precision. Hmmm...

Comment: The explanations here look promising: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13875

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Precision loss wouldn't cause this and `numpy.log(float(math.factorial(21)))` works fine. It's 21! not fitting into int64 anymore (20! still does).

Comment: What don't you implement logarithm of factorial with sum of logarithms instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following mathematical phrases are equal:

```
log(1 x 2 x 3 x ... x N) = log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(N)
```

Which means the following functions are equal:

```py
# Logarithm of factorial
def f1(n):
    return math.log(math.factorial(n))

# Sum of logarithms
def f2(n): 
    return np.sum( np.log( np.arange(1, n+1) ) )
```

which in the second one, the chance of reaching to the maximum value of an integer in `f1()` is higher.